# Issue in Installing components through Bower from GitHub

Tags: github, bower

When I tried to create an application with help of JHipster there some issues in fetching the components through git hub with bower.

Currently tried in another way to pull the components directly with help Bower but couldn't

I tried in two ways (i) with git & (ii) with https, both the ways it is getting failed.

Attached the screenshot below for your reference.

Kindly let me know in case of more information.

[image: Error Installing in JHipster]

[image: Error Installing with help of Bower]

Answer (score 1):

Would you be behind a proxy ? It seems you can't reach github.com on the git port (9418). If that 's the case configure your git to use https:// instead of git://

Comment: How to change this? because the jhipster takes configures it automatically

Comment: I added a above a screenshot is it right? or i'm in wrong path?

Comment: I already added the proxy with respect to my organization, but inorder to set to port 9418 especially for this link what should i do?